# Android DialogFragment retrieving selected option

Tags: java, android

I've basically got a dialogfragment which shows a range of options.

What i am trying to do is,

pass back to the calling activity, which option was selected. This will then, in the original activity call a method.

ATM I am using,

((Activity) method(); , to call the calling activities method from within the dialog,
but this seems to be very in efficient as android response time slows down when doing this.

**In other words, How can i simply, and quickly get information back from the fragment i just created?**

In activity,

```
button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0)  {

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragClass frag = new FragClass();
            frag.show(fm, "fragment_sub_connections");

        }
```

and then in FragClass,

```
    public FragClass()
{


}



@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_connections, container);
            //some code here
}
```

Comment: i dont think response time will slow down just by calling method, maybe the method has some heavy processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Listener Interface and allow your activity to implement it, this can be used as a callback.

```
// In your fragment

public interface OnMyFragDismissListener(){
     void onMyFragDismissed(MyObject obj);
}    

// onCreate...

// someCode...

// However you have the user select the option
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface d){
     if(getActivity() instanceof OnMyFragDismissListener)}
        ((OnMyFragDismissListener)getActivity()).onMyFragDismissed(result); // result being the user choice
     }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnMyFragDismissListener {

   // code...
    FragmentManager fragman = getFragmentManager();
    FragClass frag = new FragClass();
    frag.show(fm, "fragment_sub_connections");


  // code...

   @Override
   public void onMyFragDismissed(MyObject obj){
        // Fragment dismissed and object received!
   }

 }
```

Comment: is there anyway to do this without having the: "

Activity implements OnMyFragDismissListener "

Comment: @rennoDeniro Make a new anonymous listener. `OnMyFragDismissListener instanceListener = new OnMyFragDismissListener(){ /** override methods here and do your thing */ };`